# How to show all client, who had more than one meeting in the restaurant

Tags: sql, oracle

wants to display all customers who had more than one meeting in the restaurant with the identifier 5

but this ask have bad results because if the client is a client for client_id 2 then doesnt count him
i have big problem if i have 2 foregin key in from the same table

```
SELECT COUNT(s.id_restaurant) amount_meet, k.id_client
FROM client k JOIN meet s ON k.id_client =s.id_client1 JOIN klient kl ON kl.id_client=s.id_client2
WHERE s.id_restaurant=5
HAVING COUNT(s.id_restaurant)>1
GROUP BY k.id_client;
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to return 1 column with all the values of `id_client1` and `id_client2` that had a meeting in `id_restaurant = 5` and aggregate on that result:

```
SELECT t.id_client, COUNT(*) amount_meet
FROM (
  SELECT id_client1 id_client FROM meet WHERE id_restaurant = 5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id_client2 FROM meet WHERE id_restaurant = 5
) t
GROUP BY t.id_client
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you try to select from meet table and joinning with client table?

```
SELECT COUNT(s.id_restaurant) amount_meet, k.id_client
FROM meet s 
LEFT JOIN client k ON k.id_client =s.id_client1 
LEFT JOIN client kl ON kl.id_client=s.id_client2
WHERE s.id_restaurant=5
HAVING COUNT(s.id_restaurant)>1
GROUP BY k.id_client;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports lateral joins.  This makes it easy to efficiently unpivot the values to do what you want:

```
select c.id_client, count(*)
from meet m cross join lateral
     (select m.id_client1 as id_client from dual union all
      select m.id_client2 as id_client from dual
     ) c
where m.id_restaurant = 5 and
      c.id_client is not null
group by c.id_client
having count(*) > 1;
```

Note:  If the same client is in the same row in both columns, then this is counted as two meetings.  You don't explain what to do in this case, so that seems like reasonable behavior.

Also note that the `client` table is not needed for this query.